# Why with resource is not executing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here in my controller i have added the EventsResource and at there i have added the with function but in output its not executing or something I can't able to figure out. I have added the output please check.
Here is my controller part.

```
class EventsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $event = Event::with('eventCategory')->get();
        return EventsResource::collection($event);

    }
```

EventsResource

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'image' => $this->image,
            'eventcategory' => $this->eventcategory->name,
            'start'=> $this->start,
            'end'=> $this->end
        ];
    }
    public function with($request)
    {
        return 
        [
            'status' => true,
            'message'=> 'sucess'
        ];
    }
```

output:

```
{
        "name": "Poetry",
        "description": "Poetry",
        "image": null,
        "eventcategory": "Weekend",
        "start": "2019-11-12 17:11:00",
        "end": "2019-11-26 17:11:00"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to create a ResourceCollection class and add that method to it.

> "If you would like to customize the resource collection response, you may create a dedicated resource to represent the collection"

Your `EventsResource` is for 1 Event and you are returning an Anonymous Resource Collection, so a single Event isn't the top level, the Collection is the top level.

> "This method [`with`] should return an array of meta data to be included with the resource response only when the resource is the outer-most resource being rendered:

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent Resources - Resource Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent Resources - Adding Meta Data](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data) `with`